# Looking for a complete list of how the 37 factors are balanced

Tags: reference-request, bodhipakkhiyadhamma

The 37 Factors are sometimes paired as balancing factors. When they are out of balance there are some implications, and there is a controlling (or pivotal) factor which is instrumental in keeping the balance.

In many publications these are scattered throughout, so I am looking for:

- balancing factors, or pair of factors which need to be balanced
- the implications of any imbalance
- associated Controlling (or Pivotal) Factors

... with references from the Canon where these appear.

Comment: You are referring to the 37 factors of enlightenment here correct? 

http://satimabhikkhuni.blogspot.com/2009/08/thirty-seven-requisites-of.html

Comment: This is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This [PDF](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/10.1-Bodhipakkhiya-Dhamma-piya.pdf) could be a useful resource, specifically the following passages:

> faith and wisdom are to be balanced
>   **so as to avoid blind belief and mere intellectual cleverness;**
>   effort and concentration are to be balanced
>   **to avoid mental restlessness and sluggishness.**
>
> Mindfulness is the key factor that keeps all the other
>   factors in balance and harmony

and

> The three factors of investigation (dhamma,vicaya), effort (viriya) and zest (piti) **counteract torpor**.
>
> The three factors of tranquillity (passaddhi), concentration (samādhi) and equanimity (upekkhā)
>   **counteract mental agitation**.
>
> Mindfulness (sati) keeps the two sets of factors in a harmonious balance.

Other than these areas I could find no references to balancing the 37 factors. Hopefully this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks. In the 37 factors there are 7 sets. I am looking for a summary including each of the sets. What you have pointed is one of the 7. Thanks for this. If you manage to locate the other 6 please add then. If somebody else does please add a new answer.

Comment: I'll keep looking, but I think that the idea of balancing does not apply to all the sets.

Comment: Take a look at the PDF, in the meantime I'll see if I can find another resource.

Comment: I know this applies to some of the sets only so in which case what does it apply to and which it does not apply to. So what I have found so far is 5 Powers, 5 Faculties and 7 Enlightenment factors. I am trying to ascertain if these are the only factors or not. Also please keep searching. Also thanks very much for your efforts.

Comment: Also another personal notion I have is in the 8 fold path is each sub division of morality, concentration and wisdom has balancing factor also. I have not still found any source to confirm my hunch on this.